# gulp merge-stream does not have add() function?

Tags: gulp

I am having an odd, late on a Friday, `gulp` `merge-stream` issue.  I am being told:

```
TypeError: merge.add is not a function
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myProject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "bootstrap-datepicker": "^1.8.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.0",
    "jquery-validation": "^1.19.0",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "^3.2.11",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "spectrum-colorpicker": "^1.8.0",
    "spin.js": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-cli": "^2.1.0",
    "merge-stream": "^1.0.1"
  }
}
```

gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var gclean = require("gulp-clean");

var paths = {
    node: "./node_modules/",
    lib: "./wwwroot/lib/"
};

var packages = {
    "bootstrap": {
        src: paths.node + "bootstrap/dist/**",
        dest: paths.lib + "bootstrap"
    },
    "bootstrap-datepicker": {
        src: paths.node + "bootstrap-datepicker/dist/**",
        dest: paths.lib + "bootstrap-datepicker"
    },
    "jquery": {
        src: paths.node + "jquery/dist/**",
        dest: paths.lib + "jquery"
    },
    "jquery-validation": {
        src: paths.node + "jquery-validation/dist/**",
        dest: paths.lib + "jquery-validation"
    },
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": {
        src: paths.node + "jquery-validation-unobtrusive/dist/**",
        dest: paths.lib + "jquery-validation-unobtrusive"
    },
    "moment": {
        src: paths.node + "moment/min/**",
        dest: paths.lib + "moment"
    },
    "popper.js": {
        src: paths.node + "popper.js/dist/umd/**",
        dest: paths.lib + "popper.js"
    },
    "spectrum-colorpicker": {
        src: paths.node + "spectrum-colorpicker/spectrum.*",
        dest: paths.lib + "spectrum-colorpicker"
    },
    "spin.js": {
        src: paths.node + "spin.js/spin.*",
        dest: paths.lib + "spin.js"
    }
};

function clean() {
    return gulp.src(paths.lib + "*", { read: false })
        .pipe(gclean());
}

function build() {
    const merge = require("merge-stream");

    for (let item in packages) {
        if (packages.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
            console.log(item);
            console.dir(packages[item]);

            merge.add(
                gulp.src(packages[item].src)
                    .pipe(gulp.dest(packages[item].dest))
            );
        }
    }

    return merge.isEmpty() ? null : merge;
}

exports.build = build;
exports.clean = clean;
exports.default = gulp.series(clean, build);
```

The command line result is:

```
> gulp
[16:32:04] Using gulpfile H:\Projects\My Projects\myProject\myProject\gulpfile.js
[16:32:04] Starting 'default'...
[16:32:04] Starting 'clean'...
[16:32:04] Finished 'clean' after 15 ms
[16:32:04] Starting 'build'...
bootstrap
{ src: './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/**',
  dest: './wwwroot/lib/bootstrap' }
[16:32:04] 'build' errored after 16 ms
[16:32:04] TypeError: merge.add is not a function
    at build (H:\Projects\My Projects\myProject\myProject\gulpfile.js:61:19)
    at bound (domain.js:395:14)
    at runBound (domain.js:408:12)
    at asyncRunner (H:\Projects\My Projects\myProject\myProject\node_modules\async-done\index.js:55:18)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
[16:32:04] 'default' errored after 43 ms
```

It has to be something simple that i am just too tired to see.  Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```js
const merge = require("merge-stream");
```

to

```js
const merge = require("merge-stream")();
```

Comment: Thank you.  Can you tell me what adding the extra parens does?

Comment: `add()` is a method of the object that `merge-stream` returns when it is invoked. That's why I added the extra parens.